# Text in horizontal bar doesn't align properly, despite having the same CSS as one that does

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have two horizontal bars that I'm trying to align. They both need to stretch the whole width of the viewport, and there is text within them that needs to be centre aligned. To do this, I'm using the following HTML:

```
<div class="logo-header-desktop">Header</div>
<ul class="logos">
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="logo-footer-desktop">
  <span class="call-button">Footer</span>
</div>
```

And the following SCSS:

```
.logo-header-desktop, .logo-footer-desktop {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        position: relative !important;
        left: -16%;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border: solid 2px #f2f2f2;
    }
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.logo-header-desktop {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        background: #202020;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.logo-footer-desktop {
    padding-top: 0;
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border-top: 0;
    }
    .call-button {
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
        background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
        padding: 20px;
        @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
            width: 100vw;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        }
        transition: color 0.2s, background-color ease-in-out 0.2s;
        transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
        &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
            background: #4b3be7;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

The header and footer are using virtually the same CSS. However, this results in the footer text being misaligned with the header text in a viewport with width over 1000px. Viewports under 1000px aren't affected.

This behaviour is reproducible in the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j6j4cck2/

Why's this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `call-button`'s padding that cause the misalignment.

Since you give it a width on wider screens, you also need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` so the padding gets included in the set width (or use CSS Calc `width: calc(100vw - 40px);`)

```
.call-button {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;                        /*  added property  */
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6j4cck2/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="logo-header-desktop">Header</div>
<ul class="logos">
  <li>Thing 1</li>
  <li>Thing 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="logo-footer-desktop">
  <span class="call-button">
        Footer
  </span>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
html {
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 2.5vmin;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #202020;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo-header-desktop, .logo-footer-desktop {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        position: relative !important;
        left: -16%;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border: solid 2px #f2f2f2;
    }
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.logo-header-desktop {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        background: #202020;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}

.logo-footer-desktop {
    padding-top: 0;
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border-top: 0;
    }
    .call-button {
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
        background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
            width: 100vw;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        }
        transition: color 0.2s, background-color ease-in-out 0.2s;
        transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
        &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
            background: #4b3be7;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}

ul.logos {
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        background: #202020;
        position: relative;
        left: -16%;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
        border: solid 2px #f2f2f2;
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
    }

    // box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    li {
        line-height: 3;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
        transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition-property: transform;
        transition-property: transform;


        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: 5%;
        }
        font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #ffffff;
        img {
            height: 7vmin;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! It's really helpful. Unfortunately, another issue seems to crop up with it :( I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6j4cck2/3/

I added a wrapper div, and now on very wide viewports, the bars sometimes don't reach the whole way across the viewport. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford The `wrapper` has both `padding` and `margin` which prevent its children from reaching beyond its width. To solve that you need to use `transform: translate` to enable a child to expand to the viewport edges. What I mean is, the `-16%` is not the correct way to make them fit the viewport width. I will make a sample to show

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford Here is 2 samples showing your original variant and with `transform: translate`: https://jsfiddle.net/j6j4cck2/4/

Comment: @CurtisParfitt-Ford As my given answer solves your original question, I would appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much. :) I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `left` attribute from those elements. You have a negative value of `-16%` set. See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a3fbjjp/3/). Delete the commented code below from your code.

```
.logo-header-desktop, .logo-footer-desktop {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    position: relative !important;
    left: -16%; /* Delete this. Line 21 */
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

And remove it from:

```
ul.logos {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    background: #202020;
    position: relative;
    left: -16%; /* Delete this. Line 72 */
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Then you need to add `box-sizing: border-box` to some elements and change the `.call-button` to 100%, since `100vh` doesn't work in a div with padding or margins.

```
ul.logos,
.logo-footer-desktop,
.call-button {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this. */
}
.call-button {
  width: 100%; /* Change from 100vh to 100%. Line 48. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `cell-button` as below to fix it:

```
.call-button {
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
        background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 1);
        padding-top: 20px; /* changed */
        padding-bottom: 20px; /* changed */
        @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
            width: 100vw;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        }
        transition: color 0.2s, background-color ease-in-out 0.2s;
        transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
        &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
            background: #4b3be7;
            color: white;
        }
    }
```